# how to create folder in blob storage

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-functions, azure-blob-storage

I have a file such as `Parent.zip` and when unzipped, it will yield these files: `child1.jpg` , `child2.txt` , `child3.pdf`.

When running `Parent.zip` through the function below, the files are correctly unzipped to:

```
some-container/child1.jpg
some-container/child2.txt
some-container/child3.pdf
```

**How do I unzip the files to their parent folder?** The desired result would be:

```
some-container/Parent/child1.jpg
some-container/Parent/child2.txt
some-container/Parent/child3.pdf
```

As you can see above the folder `Parent` was created.

I am using this to create the files in blob:

```
            using (var stream = entry.Open ()) {
                //check for file or folder and update the above blob reference with actual content from stream
                if (entry.Length > 0) {
                    await blob.UploadFromStreamAsync (stream);
                }
            }
```

Here's the full source:

```
[FunctionName ("OnUnzipHttpTriggered")]
public static async Task<IActionResult> Run (
    [HttpTrigger (AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
    ILogger log) {
    log.LogInformation ("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");

    var requestBody = new StreamReader (req.Body).ReadToEnd ();
    var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ZipFileMetaData> (requestBody);
    var storageAccount =
        CloudStorageAccount.Parse (Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable ("StorageConnectionString"));
    var blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient ();
    var container = blobClient.GetContainerReference (data.SourceContainer);
    var blockBlob = container.GetBlockBlobReference (data.FileName);
    var extractcontainer = blockBlob.ServiceClient.GetContainerReference (data.DestinationContainer.ToLower ());
    await extractcontainer.CreateIfNotExistsAsync ();

    var files = new List<string> ();
    // Save blob(zip file) contents to a Memory Stream.
    using (var zipBlobFileStream = new MemoryStream ()) {
        await blockBlob.DownloadToStreamAsync (zipBlobFileStream);
        await zipBlobFileStream.FlushAsync ();
        zipBlobFileStream.Position = 0;
        //use ZipArchive from System.IO.Compression to extract all the files from zip file
        using (var zip = new ZipArchive (zipBlobFileStream)) {
            //Each entry here represents an individual file or a folder
            foreach (var entry in zip.Entries) {
                files.Add (entry.FullName);
                //creating an empty file (blobkBlob) for the actual file with the same name of file
                var blob = extractcontainer.GetBlockBlobReference (entry.FullName);
                using (var stream = entry.Open ()) {
                    //check for file or folder and update the above blob reference with actual content from stream
                    if (entry.Length > 0) {
                        await blob.UploadFromStreamAsync (stream);
                    }
                }

                // TO-DO : Process the file (Blob)
                //process the file here (blob) or you can write another process later
                //to reference each of these files(blobs) on all files got extracted to other container.
            }
        }
    }

    return new OkObjectResult (files);
}
```

Comment: in blob storage all folders are virtual folder. So if you create a blob with name `Parent/child1.jpg` you will see `child1.jpg` is under a folder name `Parent`

Comment: @NafisIslam - probably a good idea to point out that blob storage doesn't have folders at all. The entire hierarchy is `blob-account/container/blob`. What seems like a folder is just a filename with `/` delimiter characters in it. This is actually called out in the answer posted here as well.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Simply add directory name before entry name, and we can see the *directory* created automatically.

```
var blob = extractcontainer.GetBlockBlobReference ("Parent/"+entry.FullName);
```

Note that the directory is virtual. Blob Storage is in `container/blob` structure, the directories are actually prefixes of blob names, and Storage service displays the directory structure according to the `/` separator for us.